# Can I change the user and password to class?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to keep the data of user and password in servelt 
I don't want to create table user and user_role but to do this logic in diffrerent class is it possible ? 
maybe to write the DB name in the dataSource ?

```
   spring-security.xml
```

```
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />          
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from user_roles where username =?" />
    </authentication-provider>

</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

Inject in configuration:

```xml
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: do you have an example for myUserDetailsService ?

Comment: @user1365697 There are a lot of examples on the web, give it a search. Or just read the javadoc what it should do.